# How do I get one column with one row and one column with two rows nested in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm looking for the easiest way to get a icon on the left vertical aligned with the two lines of text on the right.

What I'm struggling with is the way I have to organize my HTML. I can functionally build this, but I think it's not efficient/clean the way I do this (too much code). So any advice on how this problem can be tackled is highly appreciated :). A screenshot from what I want to achieve is below. I'm using Font Awesome and Bootstrap 3 for development.

[Screenshot of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBvoS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add div display to table-row

https://jsfiddle.net/q2x9sLo9/

Address

Mirpur New Bazar Road, Dhaka-12101

```
<div style="background-color:#00ced1;display: table-row;">
<i class="fa fa-envelope" style="float:left; padding:18px; background-color:#00ced1; color:white; font-size:40px"></i>
<div style="float:left; background-color:#00ced1; color:white;">
<h4>
E-mail
</h4><p>
example@info.com
</p>
</div>
</div>

<div style="background-color:#00ced1;display: table-row;">
<i class="fa fa-phone" style="float:left; padding:18px; background-color:#00ced1; color:white; font-size:59px"></i>
<div style="float:left; background-color:#00ced1; color:white;">
<h4>
Phone
</h4><p>
(732) 803-01 03
</p>
</div>``
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for a usage without using table

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? Just change the image used and the text, and whatever you need to change

```css
.col-xs-12 {
  background-color: pink;
}

._imgContainer {
  position: relative;
}

._imgContainer>._icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,25%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 _imgContainer">
          <image class="_icon" src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fullscreen-Image-Viewer-Chroma-Gallery.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 _textContainer">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box{padding:10px; background:#7cc5ef;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="container">
<h1>Contact Address</h1><br>
 <div class="row text-center">
  
  <table class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 box">
          <tr >
             <th class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" style="font-size:30px;"></th>
             <td> <b>Phone</b></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td> +01-009940-998569></td>
         </tr>
         
               <tr >
             <th class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="font-size:30px;"></th>
             <td> <b>Location</b></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td> 6th Sun Road</td>
         </tr>
               <tr >
             <th class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" style="font-size:30px;"></th>
             <td> <b>E-mail</b></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td> info@sun.com</td>
         </tr>
               <tr >
             <th class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf" style="font-size:30px;"></th>
             <td> <b>Web</b></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td> me@me.com</td>
         </tr>
        
        </table>
        </div>
</div>
```